# Why am I getting 0 (zero) when accessing a numeric attribute of a nodelist generated by getElementsByTagName?

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist

Why can I not get any of the numeric attributes?

My code is as follows:

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img");  
console.log( "\'img[0].namespaceURI\' results in " + img[0].namespaceURI );
console.log( "\'img[0].height\' results in " + img[0].height );
console.log(img);
```

Strings work. But none of the numeric values...

See image
[image]

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox 26 and Chrome 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the image hasn't fully loaded yet. Use an `onload` handler.

```
var img = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];  
img.onload = function() {
    console.log( "\'img[0].namespaceURI\' results in " + this.namespaceURI );
    console.log( "\'img[0].height\' results in " + this.height );
    console.log(this);
};
```

If there's a possibility that the image is cached, then you can check its `.complete` property and invoke the handler manually if needed.

```
if (img.complete) 
    img.onload();
```

Comment: @t.niese gives a great explanation! But marking this as answer cause also has a how to address it. As an aside, I had to do `img[0].onload` to get it to work. Thanks guys for the help!

Comment: Yeah, sorry I somehow didn't notice that you were using `.getElementsByTagName()`.

Answer (score 1):

The *outline* of an DOM element in the console reflects the state it has when you click on the arrow to show the *outline* (depending on the version of the browser its content is also updated when the dom changes while the outline is open). `console.log(img);` logs *reference*  to the element not the state of the element at the time where you call `console.log(img);`

While the `console.log` of `img[0].height` shows the value of `height` of the image at the time where you do the logging, because you request the `height` directly and because it is a primitiv.  So if the image is not loaded at that time the `height` shown when you call `console.log(img[0].height)` is `0`.

You need to wait until the images is loaded to get its *calculated*  values.

This behavior for `console.log` / `console.dir` is the same for all non primitives. Object, Arrray, DOMElements, ... are passed as reference to the console. String, Numbers, Bools are passed by value to the console output.